# Removing characters from a string in Nyquist

Tags: lisp, audacity, nyquist

How can I remove a certain character from a string in Nyquist (which is very similar to xlisp) and have the result returned?

I want to count how many "A" there are in a string like "ABBAAAABBBAABAAAB". (Yes, there are only 'A's and 'B's in the string.)

Since there is no (count) function in Nyquist I tried something like

```
(length (remove #\B mystring))
```

or

```
(length (remove #\B mystring :test equal))
```

But it doesn't work.

Forgetting the character count for a moment, how can I remove the 'B's from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will there always be only `A`s and `B`s in the string? If not, you might want to do something like

```
(remove #\A yourstring :test-not 'char=)
```

According to the [XLISP reference for `remove`](http://www.audacity-forum.de/download/edgar/nyquist/nyquist-doc/xlisp/xlisp-ref/xlisp-ref-218.htm), the Nyquist `remove` doesn't deal with `string`s, only `list`s. You need to convert a `string` to a `list` in order to operate on it this way, but there's no `coerce` either. It's a touch hacky, but the easiest way around it I see is to stream a `string` and `read-char` it. This will produce a `list` of `char`s that you can then manipulate with `remove`.

```
(defun string->list (a-string)
  (let ((collector nil)
        (stream (make-string-input-stream a-string)))
    (dotimes (c (length a-string) (reverse collector))
      (setf collector (cons (read-char stream) collector)))))
```

It should now be possible to

```
(remove #\A (string->list yourstring) :test-not 'char=)
```

Comment: Unluckily it doesn't work. "(setf yourstring "ABBAABABCCCCBBCCCCAAA")
(print (remove #\A yourstring :test-not 'char=))" results in "error: bad argument type - "ABBAABABCCCCBBCCCCAAA"
Function: #<Subr-REMOVE: #168bbe8>
Arguments:
  #\A
  "ABBAABABCCCCBBCCCCAAA"
  :TEST-NOT
  CHAR=
1> "

Comment: @David Costa - did you try it with `'equal`?

Comment: Same error. The interpreter says mystring is of the wrong type. And in effect there are no strings in the examples.

Comment: @David Costa - Hm. Good point; I had tested this in Common Lisp (where your original works fine, by the way). If the error is about the type of `mystring`, it might be that strings are represented differently than standard sequences in XLISP. Is there a `coerce` function or similar you could use to convert a `string` to a list of `char`s?

Comment: Apparently there is no coerce function in the reference.

Comment: @David Costa - Wow. That's a pretty gimped Lisp implementation now that I really look at it; you don't even have a proper CL Loop to work with. Try the definition of `string->list` I just posted. `(remove #\A (string->list yourstring) :test-not 'char=)` should work (I didn't test it as I don't have a Nyquist interpreter here, so it may need some fine tuning).

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question, but since it has over 800 views, it's perhaps worth having the simple answer:

```
(defun remove-char (character sequence)
  (let ((out ""))
    (dotimes (i (length sequence) out)
      (setf ch (char sequence i))
      (unless (char= ch character)
        (setf out (format nil "~a~a" out ch))))))

(setf mystring "ABBAABABCCCCBBCCCCAAA")
(remove-char #\B mystring) ;returns "AAAACCCCCCCCAAA"
```